# Conditional formula format with entered values and answer

Tags: conditionals, luacode, formulas

With the luacode below I have tried to generate a conditional formula format with entered values including answer. However, it seems unnecessarily complicated and the formula formatting does not work. At the bottom the desired result but manually. How can this be done better and more efficiently?

[image: formula]

```
\documentclass[paper=A4, 11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
function beta (a, L)
    local o
    local beta = a / L
    o = string.format("%.2f", beta)
    tex.print(o)
end
function formula_variable (xi, a, L)
    local o
    local beta = a / L
    local left = "-1/2*beta^2*xi + beta*xi - 1/2*xi + 1/6*beta^3 - 1/2*beta + 1/3"
    local right = "1/6*xi^3 - 1/2*beta*xi^2 + beta*xi - 1/2*xi - 1/2*beta + 1/3"
    if (xi >= 0 and xi < beta) then
        o = string.format(left)
    else
        o = string.format(right)
    end
    tex.sprint(string.format(o,xi,beta))
end
function formula_entered (xi, a, L)
    local o
    local beta = a / L
    local left = "-1/2*beta^2*xi + beta*xi - 1/2*xi + 1/6*beta^3 - 1/2*beta + 1/3"
    local right = "1/6*xi^3 - 1/2*beta*xi^2 + beta*xi - 1/2*xi - 1/2*beta + 1/3"
    if (xi >= 0 and xi < beta) then
        o = left
    else
        o = right
    end
    tex.sprint(string.format(o,xi,beta))
end
function formula_answer (xi, a, L)
    local o
    local beta = a / L
    local left = -1/2*beta^2*xi + beta*xi - 1/2*xi + 1/6*beta^3 - 1/2*beta + 1/3
    local right = 1/6*xi^3 - 1/2*beta*xi^2 + beta*xi - 1/2*xi - 1/2*beta + 1/3
    if (xi >= 0 and xi < beta) then
        o = string.format("%.4f", left)
    else
        o = string.format("%.4f", right)
    end
    tex.print(o)
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode*}

\def\XI{0.5}
\def\L{5.0}     % length
\def\a{3.5}     % distance
\def\BETA{\directlua{beta(\a,\L)}}

\newcommand{\FORMULA}[1]{\directlua{formula_variable(#1)}}
\newcommand{\ENTERED}[1]{\directlua{formula_entered(#1)}}
\newcommand{\ANSWER}[1]{\directlua{formula_answer(#1)}}

Automatic (but not as desired)
\begin{align*}
  y_{max}   &= \FORMULA{\XI,\a,\L}\\
            &= \ENTERED{\XI,\a,\L}\\
            &= \ANSWER{\XI,\a,\L}
\end{align*}

Manual (with formatting as desired)
\begin{align*}
  y_{max}   &= -\frac{1}{2}\cdot\beta^2\cdot\xi
                + \beta\cdot\xi
                - \frac{1}{2}\cdot\xi
                + \frac{1}{6}\cdot\beta^3
                - \frac{1}{2}\cdot\beta
                + \frac{1}{3}\\
            &= -\frac{1}{2}\cdot\BETA^2\cdot\XI
                + \BETA\cdot\XI
                - \frac{1}{2}\cdot\XI
                + \frac{1}{6}\cdot\BETA^3
                - \frac{1}{2}\cdot\BETA
                + \frac{1}{3}\\
            &= \ANSWER{\XI,\a,\L}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fundamentally you need to enter the formula twice anyway (once in Lua format with `*` for multiplication, and another in TeX format with `\cdot` for multiplication), so I don't understand what you're trying to optimize.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I would like to run the conditional condition from luacode. I thought maybe there would be a way to measure the format as well. That would make it easier. I'm looking for a good example.

Comment: I've added some meta code to inform the system that a part of the code block should be displayed as Lua code rather than as LaTeX code. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=A4, 11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
function beta ( a , L )
    tex.sprint ( string.format ( "%.2f" , a/L ) )
end

function formula_variable ( xi , a , L )
    local beta, zz
    beta  = a / L
    if ( xi >= 0 and xi < beta ) then
       zz = "-1/2*\\beta^2*\\xi + \\beta*\\xi - 1/2*\\xi + 1/6*\\beta^3 - 1/2*\\beta + 1/3"
    else
       zz = "1/6*\\xi^3 - 1/2*\\beta*\\xi^2 + \\beta*\\xi - 1/2*\\xi - 1/2*\\beta + 1/3"
    end
    tex.sprint ( zz )
end

function formula_entered (xi, a, L)
    local beta, zz
    beta  = a / L
    if ( xi >= 0 and xi < beta ) then
       zz = ""..(-1/2).."*"..(beta^2).."*" ..xi.. "+" ..beta.. "*" ..xi..(-1/2).."*"..xi.. "+"..string.format("%.4f",1/6).."*"..(beta^3)..(-1/2).."*"..beta.."+"..string.format("%.4f",1/3)
    else
       zz = "1/6*"..(xi^3).."-1/2*"..beta.."*"..(xi^2).."+"..beta.."*"..xi.."-1/2*"..xi.."-1/2*"..beta.."+1/3"
    end
    tex.sprint ( zz )
end
    
function formula_answer (xi, a, L)
    local beta, zz
    beta  = a / L
    if ( xi >= 0 and xi < beta ) then
       zz = -(1/2)*beta^2*xi + beta*xi - (1/2)*xi + (1/6)*beta^3 - (1/2)*beta + (1/3)
    else
       zz = (1/6)*xi^3 - (1/2)*beta*xi^2 + beta*xi - (1/2)*xi - (1/2)*beta + (1/3)
    end
    tex.sprint ( string.format ( "%.4f" , zz ) )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode*}

\def\XI{0.5}
\def\L{5.0}     % length
\def\a{3.5}     % distance
\def\BETA{\directlua{beta(\a,\L)}}

\newcommand{\FORMULA}[1]{\directlua{formula_variable(#1)}}
\newcommand{\ENTERED}[1]{\directlua{formula_entered(#1)}}
\newcommand{\ANSWER}[1]{\directlua{formula_answer(#1)}}

Automatic
\begin{align*}
  y_{\max}   
     &= \FORMULA{\XI,\a,\L} \\
     &= \ENTERED{\XI,\a,\L} \\
     &= \ANSWER{\XI,\a,\L}
\end{align*}

Manual
\begin{align*}
  y_{\max}   
     &= -\tfrac{1}{2}\cdot\beta^2\cdot\xi
        + \beta\cdot\xi
        - \tfrac{1}{2}\cdot\xi
        + \tfrac{1}{6}\cdot\beta^3
        - \tfrac{1}{2}\cdot\beta
        + \tfrac{1}{3} \\
     &= -\tfrac{1}{2}\cdot\BETA^2\cdot\XI
        + \BETA\cdot\XI
        - \tfrac{1}{2}\cdot\XI
        + \tfrac{1}{6}\cdot\BETA^3
        - \tfrac{1}{2}\cdot\BETA
        + \tfrac{1}{3} \\
     &= \ANSWER{\XI,\a,\L}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting! But I think as said at the beginning it won't quite work. Perhaps it is better to process the "if (xi >= 0 and xi < beta) then .. else.." in the TeX format and use Luacode only for calculations. But How?

Comment: @PaulJGD - As you may have inferred from my "Something like this?" question, I'm not at all sure as to what exactly you want to achieve. Unfortunately, claims such as "it won't quite work" are not actionable. If you want the respective first lines of the two `align*` environments to be the same, all you need to do is (a) replace the inline-fraction expressions with equivalent `\frac` (or `\tfrac`) expressons and (b) replace the `*` symbols with `\cdot`. That's not difficult, is it? FWIW, I actually thought it was the *middle row* that was at the center of your attention; clearly, I was wrong.

Comment: @Miko - I took your advice and it works now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Miko - It works great! One last question. For long equations I want to use the multiline environment with insert a double backslash at the point for the equation to be broken. How can I include that in the luacode \FORMULA and \ENTERED? I've tried but without success.

Comment: @PaulJGD - I would suggest that you load the `mathtools` package, which is a superset of the `amsmath` package, and employ its `multlined` environment instead of a `multline` environment. (Be sure to enter the double backslash as `\\\\\``). To align the `multlined` environment correctly relative to the `=` symbol, be sure to write `\\begin{multlined}[t]`, not just `\\begin{multlined}`. BTW, I've noticed that you haven't upvoted or accepted my answer. It it really worth that little to you?

Comment: @Miko - It works! Thank you.